# How do I display full equations when calling for a function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

**I have a problem about displaying the output in the way I need it to, first let me show what I'm trying to do**

*The problem I'm trying to solve:*

> Write a function called printaltsum that takes an integer and prints the sum from 1 to the integer, where the addition and subtraction are alternated.
>
> For example- printaltsum(4) **MUST** display **exactly** the following:
>
> 1=1
>
> 1+2=3
>
> 1+2-3=0
>
> 1+2-3+4=4

---

Please guide me in the right direction, I have been able to solve this problem to get final values, but I just can't get it to display the format it needs (all I get is the Right hand side of the equation and final value as answer).

When I call for my function it displays :

printaltsum(4)

1

3

0

4

ans =

```
 4
```

*as you can see I can't display the equations, but only the Right hand side of it and the final answer*

---

**Here is my code:**

```
function sum = printaltsum(n)



sum=0;



for i=1:n;

        if i==1

           sum=1;

         

        end

            if rem(i,2)==0 && i ~=1

               sum=sum+i;

            end

            if rem(i,2)==1 && i ~=1

                sum=sum-i;

            end

            

disp(sum)

end



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assembel the String to display yourselve, matlab wont do it. 
So just add to every Operation the same in text.

first initialize an empty string:

```
str='';
```

When ever you do something to the sum, you do the same to the string in text, for example:

```
sum=1; % setting sum to 1
str='1'% the same in text
```

or for inside the loop:

```
sum=sum+i; % adding i to sum
str=[str '+' num2str(i)]% the same in text
```

at the end of the loop you can display the string:

```
disp(str)
```

Hope this helps